# How to use routing in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a vue js project, to use the router , I installed via command -> npm install vue-router and created a router.js file , but when i try , npm run serve, i get compile warnings and the app doesn't work as intended.

**Error**

> warning in ./src/router.js
>
> export 'default' (imported as 'Router') was not found in 'vue-router' ( possible exports: NavigationFailureType, RouterLink ....)

**Directory Structure**

```
vuejsproj
  > node_modules
  > public
  > src
      > assets
      > components 
      App.vue
      main.js
      router.js
    ...
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
Vue.use(Router);
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      alias: "/list",
      name: "list",
      component: () => import("./components/somecomponent")
    }
  ]
});
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import router from './router'
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts":{
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.015",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0"
  },
  
}
```

Comment: you are using vue-router 4 - but using vue-router 3 methodology - change `"vue-router": "^4.015"` to `"vue-router": "^3.5.0"` - re-install your mode modules, and you'll be fine

Comment: alternatively - read vue-router 4 docs to see how you use vue-router 4 - assuming you can use vue-router 4 with vue 2